# PlayBook Webworks cannot read local files

Tags: ajax, blackberry, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

I'm making a PlayBook webworks application. I am having problems reading a local file.

I want to make an XSLT transformation using a remote XML and a local xsl file.

I am able to download an external xml file using XMLHttpRequest, but i cannot read a local file.

I tried to read it unsing the `local:///` and using relative path, but always get my `XMLhttprequest status response code = 0`.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, 
Jordi Gaset

Answer (score 1):

Local file access in WebWorks is [not supported yet](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/Playbook-local-file-access/m-p/913963/highlight/true#M10418) as of the v1.0.0.23 Beta3 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the only way I could get this to work was to store my local data as json instead of xml, then make use of the sql lite HTML5 database to store anything inside of the app.  I think the webworks sdk needs to have their own implementation of the xmlhttprequest object that gets around all of these crazy cross-domain issues.  I tried for a while to use webworks, gave up, and started to use the air sdk.